# Selecting Attribute and listing Value base on NODE Value using Xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

How do i get All Attribute Value ID of every node FLOWER?

```
<Files>
<data id="1"> 
   <Type>Flower</Type>
</data>
<data id="2">
   <Type>Flower</Type>
</data>
<data id="3">
   <Type>Flower</Type>
 </data>
<data id="4"> 
   <Type>Flower</Type>
 </data>
</Files>
```

In mysql case it will be like `SELECT id from Files WHERE Type="Flower"`

How do i code xpath for this condition?

and List it using SimpleXML within option box.

```
<select>
<?php
foreach ($type as $id) {
echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$id.'</option>';
} 
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all `@id` attribute's values try

```
/Files/data[normalize-space(Type) = 'Flower']/@id
```

Comment: Thanks Selected as answer because it's more simpler than the previous answer! Although both works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
'//data[(./Type/text()="Flower")]/@id'
```

Comment: Thanks Works ! But I got a simpler Answered syntax wise.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is invalid, the closing root element does not match and the `Type` elements are closed as `type`. XML is case sensitive.

Xpath works uses location paths and conditions a location path is a hierarchical path to the element from the current context. They return a list of nodes. The list can be filtered using conditions.

SimpleXMLElement objects have a method `xpath()` to execute an expression in the context of the associated node.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<Files>
<data id="1"> 
   <type>Flower</type>
</data>
<data id="2">
   <type>Flower</type>
</data>
<data id="3">
   <type>Flower</type>
 </data>
<data id="4"> 
   <type>Flower</type>
 </data>
</Files>
XML;

$files = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$target = new SimpleXMLElement('<select/>');
foreach ($files->xpath('data[type = "Flower"]') as $data) {
echo '.';
  $option = $target->addChild('option', $data['id']);
  $option['value'] = $data['id'];
}
echo $target->asXml();
```

You should not create you XML as text. Use an XML Api for it.

DOM is more specific and powerful. For example you can serialize the created DOM as HTML.

```
$source = new DOMDocument();
$source->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($source);
$target = new DOMDocument();
$select = $target->appendChild($target->createElement('select'));

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/Files/data[type = "Flower"]') as $data) {
  $option = $select->appendChild($target->createElement('option'));
  $option->setAttribute('value', $data->getAttribute('id'));
  $option->appendChild($target->createTextNode($data->getAttribute('id')));
}
echo $target->saveHtml($select);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i used the answer Feel free to use the code if you like.
Thanks!!

```
<?php
//I have used 2 given answer as example on how i used it. Feel Free to use the code below
$type = $_GET['type'];
if(file_exists("xml/data.xml")) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xml/data.xml') or die("Data Missing"); }
<!-- Code Example 1 -->
$ids = $xml->xpath('//data[(./Type/text()="'.$type.'")]/@id');
<!-- Code Example 2 -->
$idx = $xml->xpath('/Files/data[normalize-space(Type) = "'.$type.'"]/@id');
?>
<!-- Example 1 -->
<select>
  <?php
//echo $ids[0];
foreach ($ids as $id) {
echo '<option value="'.$id[0].'">'.$id[0].'</option>';
} 
?>
</select>
<!-- Example 2 -->
<select>
  <?php
//echo $ids[0];
foreach ($idx as $id2) {
echo '<option value="'.$id2[0].'">'.$id2[0].'</option>';
} 
?>
</select>
<a href="logout.php">Logout
</a>
```